# .visible-xs-* does not work at 767px ? same with .visible-sm-* which does not work at 991px? and so on

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

[text not seen at 767px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvRV5.png)[text visible at 766px and below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2IdQ.png)I have been researching on this for long and I could not get that answered and hence had post this question.
You declare an html element to be visible in mobile device and include .visible-xs-block and also include .visible-sm-block for another element to be visible in ipad/ tablet mode. These work absolutely fine for all pixels except at 767px and 991px. Why is it? 
As per my understanding .visible-xs-* should work for all device sizes < 768px!!

I am struggling to resolve this just by using default bootstrap settings. Can someone help. Thanks a ton!

Comment: [Seems to be working fine for me](https://image.ibb.co/dtfmo5/Capture.jpg)

Comment: @DrewKennedy could you check my screenshots I just added.

Comment: Do you have any other CSS involved, or just Bootstrap?

Comment: Just bootstrap.. but I would be needing a CSS files when I build the project, but for now I am trying to understand whats going on.

Comment: I dunno man. Bootstrap doesn't voluntarily have it work for only some people. Try clearing your browser's cache. It also might depend on your version of Bootstrap. I believe `.visible-*` is deprecated as of v3.2.

Comment: Nope. I tried clearing browser cache and still the same. We have the same responsive utility classes in v3.3.7 as well. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: @cheresdb i am also facing this problem i have placed visible-xs on a image. It shows image below 767px but not particularly at 767px. do you find solution ??

Comment: I also face the same problem, any solution found yet? :/